# How to grep for a string with punctuation characters included?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to grep(newbie to regular expressions) for the string on the right side of the following assignment in a source tree:

```
some_var = %1$s %2$s ID
```

I have tried:

```
grep -ri '[[:punct:]]1[[:punct:]]s [[:punct:]]2[[:punct:]]s ID' . 

grep -ri "'[[:punct:]]1[[:punct:]]s'\|'[[:punct:]]2[[:punct:]]s ID'" .
```

I've ran:

```
grep -ri some_var .
```

And this returned some_var but having trouble figuring out how to return the other side of the assignment operator.

I've read through gnu grep character classes and bracket expressions but it's still not clear to me.

Comment: There are online regex tools you can use to craft a general solution using many different types of regex flavours.

Comment: The first of your grep commands works for me.  Would you clarify what problem you were having with it?

Comment: @John1024 Well it doesn't break and it seemed as if it is searching for something but when the search finished nothing was returned. I know the string `%1$s %2$s ID` is in a few files so I was expecting the string to be returned and it's location in the source tree.

Comment: @f-torr I copied your sample from the question to a file.  I ran your first grep command (__not__ the second one) and it successfully returned the path/file and the matching line.  Is the string in your files somehow subtly different from the example line in the question?

Comment: The first `grep` command works for me as well.

Comment: @John1024 No. Ok, I'll try again.. I don't have my work laptop with me right now though. I'll have to wait until Monday. Thank you!

Comment: `egrep -o '%.*ID' file`

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*' '$1 == "some_var" { print $2 }'
```

or `sed`:

```
sed 's/^some_var[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\(.*\)/\1/'
```

---

If you want to use `grep` you need to use GNU grep with perl regexes:

```
grep -oP '^some_var\s*=\s*\K.*'
```

But as I said, that works only with GNU grep and is not standard.

Comment: First, thank you for the response and help. I need to rephrase and sorry for not being as clear as I should have been. I need only to grep for the right side of the assignment operator,i.e. %1$s %2$s ID.

Comment: Well, then just use `awk -F' = ' '$2 == "%$1s %2$s ID"{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the left side with GNU sed:

```
$ sed 's/^some_var\s=\s*//' <<< "some_var = %1$s %2$s ID"
%1 %2 ID
```